# Copy Team Project Collection in TFS2012

Tags: tfs

I have a Team Project Collection that contains multiple projects-
[image]

I need to make another Team Project Collection with the same set of projects. Is there a was to copy/duplicate my original Team Project Collection in TFS2012?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "restore based move" option from the [MSDN article: Team Foundation Server Move Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404860.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the project collection and duplicate it's DB with different name and reattached both of them DBs and Project collections as well.

You can see the following post on how to do that, but this post show from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 but it's the same idea.

[Migrate and Upgrade TFS Collection from TFS 2010 to TFS 11 Beta Video](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/migrate-and-upgrade-tfs-collection-from-tfs-2010-to-tfs-11-beta-video/)

You can also see more info about managing project using TFS Project Collection here:

[Visual Studio TFS Team Project and Collection Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983486.aspx)